# Shuffle Array, Splice Array. Action script 2

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-2

Good afternoon programmers. I am trying to create a game in action script 2. the concept is that the game randomly picks an object. The player has to get the object, then the game calls out a different random object. (these objects are in an array).

```
static private var oneArray:Array = new Array("milk","cheese","bread");
static private var randomItem:String = oneArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * oneArray.length)];
```

So you can see I've done this.
Now the game will display the text;

```
    _root.hud.getItem.text = randomItem;
```

From the code above you can see that the text field will pick a randomeItem from that array.

```
    if (randomItem == ("milk"))
    {
        if (_root.milk.hitTest(_root.player._x + 60, _root.player._y - 60, true) || _root.milk.hitTest(_root.player._x - 60, _root.player._y - 60, true)) 
        {
            trace("got milk");
            _root.milk.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
```

The code you see above means that if the text field displays "milk" and if the player touches the milk, then the milk goes away.

Now when the collision is true, I want the textfield to display another random item from the array, but I don't want the same name to appear. 
I've tried splicing milk from the array but the textfield still displays the text "milk".

It doesn't update basically.

I've tried my best, and sorry if the information provided above isn't the best.
Can someone please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap last and random selected item in `oneArray`, and decrease random multiplier(`len`) so the last item(previously random selected) will never bother again.

```
private var oneArray:Array = new Array("milk","cheese","bread");
private var len:int = oneArray.length - 1;
private var rand:int;
private var randomItem:String;
```

select random item

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
randomItem = oneArray[rand];
_root.hud.getItem.text = randomItem;
```

the collision is true

```
var item:String = oneArray[rand];
oneArray[rand] = oneArray[len];
oneArray[len] = item;
len--;

if (len < 0) { 
    //goto next level
}
else {
   // and select random item again
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!
One more question, if you don't mind answering...

When the array is empty, i want it to go to the next frame lets say
(if array is empty) {go to next frame} would this be..if(oneArray.length = 0) {this.goto...etc)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time. Thank you!