# Program crashes due to text being null. [As3]

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
```

Hello guys, I get this error when I restart my program.

In the main class I have these variables

```
    //random
    private var colourArray:Array = new Array("Red","Yellow","Green");
    private var len:int = colourArray.length - 1;
    private var rand:int;
    private var randomItem:String;      
    private var myText:TextField;
```

then I have a loop that chest only the collision function

```
    private function Collision():void 
    {
        if (randomItem == ("Red"))
        {
            if (player.hitTestObject(red))
            {
                changeColor();
                red.removeMe();
            }
        }
        else
        if (randomItem == ("Yellow"))
        {
            if (player.hitTestObject(yellow))
            {
                changeColor();
                yellow.removeMe();
            }               

        }
        else
        if (randomItem == ("Green"))
        {
            if (player.hitTestObject(green))
            {
                changeColor();
                green.removeMe();
            }               
        }
    }

    private function changeColor():void 
    {
        var item:String = colourArray[rand];
        colourArray[rand] = colourArray[len];
        colourArray[len] = item;
        len--;
        randomItem = colourArray[rand];
        myText.text = randomItem;

        if (len < 0) 
        { 
            removeChild(player);
            removeChild(myText);

            colourArray.push("Red");
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop)
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkClicks)
            gotoAndStop(1);
        }

    }
```

When I try and restart the program it doesn't like ;

```
            randomItem = colourArray[rand];
```

For some reason.

I have repopulated the array, but I do not understand.

Thank you.

If you need more information please do ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store `colourArray[rand]` elsewhere prior to altering the array. You are lowering its length, then you query the element out of the array, so if your `rand` points to the last element, it gets kicked out of the array and replaced by NULL, and then you query the array again - the program says hello NULL, I panic. You already store that value in `item` variable, but don't use it for some weird reason. A fix is replace the `randomItem = colourArray[rand];` with `randomItem = item;`

Comment: Vesper, great contributor to the AS3 newbie community.push(me) and me only! haha. Thank you. I will try this, i'm just having a few bugs I need to fix first. Thank you.

Comment: here is some more information. A while back, I had help with random shuffling thanks to a friendly contributor. 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199912/shuffle-array-splice-array-action-script-2)
I still get errors with the recommended changes. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to you I figured it out. 

The program panicked because the length of the array was 0, and could not get any information.

To restarted the program, len would have to = the length of the array, which can be either 2, or myArray.length.

Thank you again Vesper.